# Clipping outside texture shader

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-shader-language

I'm trying to create a shader which decides the silhouette of the sprite by giving a texture (sampler2D) as input in shader parameter and clips anything outside it's bound

And so far this is what I've been able to come up with:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D clip_texture;

void fragment(){
    vec4 color = texture(clip_texture, UV);
    
    if(color.a==0.0)
        COLOR=vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    else
        COLOR=texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    
}
```

But this approach seems to squeeze the `Clip Texture` to the sprite resolution

[image]

I'm guessing UV being between 0.0 - 1.0 for both has something to do with this

So how do I fix this ?

**Edit: further explanation on what I'm trying to achieve**

Assume an image placed on top of another image (The image being placed on top will be passed as shader parameter)
[image]

Now if we crop only the overlapping part:
[image]

Now ofc we should also be able to move the location of the image placed on top (maybe pass x-y shader parameters?) and get the same effect:
[image] [image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve using shaders

Comment: Yes, UVs, I don't know what the transformation should be.

Comment: @Theraot does the edit clear up what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the 0.0 - 1.0 is the UV from `icon.png`, so 1.0 maps the extents of the clip texture to 64x64, shrinking it.

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D clip_texture;
uniform vec2 clip_texture_size;

void fragment(){
    vec2 texture_size = 1.0 / TEXTURE_PIXEL_SIZE;
    vec2 texture_ratio = texture_size / clip_texture_size;
    vec2 clip_UV = UV * texture_ratio;

    vec4 color = texture(clip_texture, clip_UV);
    
    if(color.a==0.0)
        COLOR=vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    else
        COLOR=texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    
}
```

For `icon.png`, `TEXTURE_PIXEL_SIZE` is equal to `vec2(1.0/64.0, 1.0/64.0)`. The reciprocal of this is the texture size: `1.0 / TEXTURE_PIXEL_SIZE`. If you divide the texture size by the clip texture size, this gives the ratio between the texture and the clip texture.

You can determine the size of a texture with `textureSize()` instead of using a uniform, but it is only available in GLES 3.

Here is a version with an offset uniform per your edit:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D clip_texture;
uniform vec2 clip_texture_size;
uniform vec2 clip_texture_offset;

void fragment(){
    vec2 texture_size = (1.0 / TEXTURE_PIXEL_SIZE);
    vec2 texture_ratio = texture_size / clip_texture_size;
    vec2 clip_UV = UV * texture_ratio + clip_texture_offset;
    
    vec4 color;
    if (clip_UV.x > 1.0 || clip_UV.x < 0.0 || clip_UV.y > 1.0 || clip_UV.y < 0.0) {
        color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    }
    else {
        color = texture(clip_texture, clip_UV);
    }
    
    if(color.a==0.0)
        COLOR=vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    else
        COLOR=texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    
}
```